# How can I put text over image card header bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to put Title over the image, I want My card-title over my image not sure do I need CSS?

here is my HTML

```
<div class="card card-blog">
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#pablo">
                <img class="img" src="assets/img/backgound.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h4 class="card-title">
                TEXT OVER IMAGE
            </h4>
            <div class="card-description">
                <div class="table-responsive">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-danger btn-round">View Article</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output : Can I move card-title over image ?

[image]

Comment: Can please add the screen shot what exactly you need?

Comment: provide a jsfiddle link, please

Comment: ok sir  i'll sec

Comment: updated @ManishPatel

Answer (score 10):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't come with any native tools to achieve this within the `card` component, but with a little additional CSS you can make it work:

```css
.card-img-caption {
  border-top-left-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
  border-top-right-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
}
  
.card-img-caption .card-img-top {
  z-index: 0;
}
    
.card-img-caption .card-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 33% 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <div class="card-img-caption">
    <p class="card-text">Test</p>
    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/130x100" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
    
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

We're encapsulating the `.card-img-top` image inside a new wrapper called `.card-img-caption` and then applying some positioning and `z-index` so that the image always lays beneath the text.

You'll likely want to fiddle with the `margin` on `.card-img-caption .card-text` as the `33%` being used here is more of a magic number than something more elegant.

If you know the dimensions of the image you're using as a background though; a smarter move might be to do just that... use a `background-image`.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old, but for those that are using Bootstrap 4, there is a native way to do this using the `card-img-overlay` class.

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
  <img class="card-img" src="..." alt="Card image">
  <div class="card-img-overlay">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#image-overlays

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```css
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 150px;
  top: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="image" src="http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg" />
  <p id="text">
    Hello World!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution using the bootstrap img-wrapper and img-overlay classes.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/mytopimage.png"/>
        <div class="img-overlay"> <h2>Text Over Image</h2> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="card-title">My Card</h2>
        <p class="card-text">My Card Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work on Bootstrap 5

Answer (score 0):

Can you add class 'carousel-caption' to the text

```
<div class="card card-blog">
    <div class="card">
        <a href="#pablo">
            <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/1000x550">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-center carousel-caption">
        <h4 class="card-title">
            TEXT OVER IMAGE
        </h4>
        <div class="card-description">
            <div class="table-responsive">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-danger btn-round">View Article</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to use `flex` class, try this!

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <a href="#pablo">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/img/backgound.jpg">
        </a>
        <h4 class="card-title">TEXT OVER IMAGE</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body text-center">
        <div class="card-description">
            <div class="table-responsive"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-danger btn-round">View Article</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```